# Is there any way to mock private functions with Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, es6-modules

The ES6 module that I want to test looks as follows:

```
function privateFunction() {
   ...
}
export function publicFunction() {
   ... does something ...
   privateFunction()
   ... does something else ...
}
```

I am using JEST for my unit tests and I am trying to find a way to test `publicFunction` and avoiding the execution of `privateFunction` by mocking it but I couldn't succeed in the mock attempt. Any idea?

Comment: Are you asking how to write a test for a private function, or how to mock a private function?

Comment: Good point. A mocking solution would be enough but both mocking/testing need a solution to access private function from the test.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found a way to mock my private function by using the `babel-plugin-rewire` module.

In `package.json` I have the following:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "babel-plugin-rewire": "1.0.0-beta-5",
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    ...
```

In `.babel.rc` I have the following:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        "babel-plugin-rewire"
      ]
    }
  },
  ...
```

At this point I was able to mock the private function:

```
import * as moduleToTest from './moduleToTest.js'

describe('#publicFunction', () => {
  it('mocks private function', () => {
    moduleToTest.__Rewire__('privateFunction', () => {
      console.log('I am the mocked private function');
    })
    ...
  })
})
```

Comment: I'm unclear how I can test this mocked function. How would I use the rewired function in the context of expect()?

Comment: @matteo, I passed through exactly the same situation. I noted that mocked private functions aren't counted on coverage.

In order to solve this coverage issue, I added the commend below on the line before the private function: `/* istanbul ignore next */`

Comment: I keep trying this, but keep getting __Rewire__ is not a function. Is there any additional setup that you are doing?

Comment: @Lounge9 to use the rewired function in the context of expect() you can do `let privateFunctionMock = jest.fn( () => { console.log('I am the mocked private function'); });`. Then, you do `moduleToTest.__Rewire__('privateFunction', privateFunctionMock);`. So you can call the `module.publicFunction();`. Now, you can assert: `expect(privateFunctionMock).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Answer (score 41):

If you want to mock a private function, try to use the `prototype`.

For example, you need to mock `privateFunction` of the following class:

```js
export class Module {
    public publicFunction() {
        // do something
        this.privateFunction();
        // do something
    }

    private privateFunction() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

So you should use `Module.prototype` in the `jest.spyOn` function.

```js
import { Module } from './my-module';

describe('MyModule', () => {
  it('tests public function', () => {
    // Arrange
    const module = new Module()
    const myPrivateFunc = jest.spyOn(Module.prototype as any, 'privateFunction');
    myPrivateFunc.mockImplementation(() => {});

    // Act
    module.publicFunction();

    // Assert
    expect(myPrivateFunc).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Comment: the accepted answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56044471/testing-private-functions-in-typescript-with-jest) helped me along this comment. Thanks !

Comment: Are there any problems/drawbacks with this solution? It works great for me but wondering if there's a catch...

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Works properly. what if the private function and the public one are in a hook instead of a class ?

Comment: If I don't (auto) mock the module it does not work with nested objects, and I usually get `TypeError: Cannot read property '(..).' of undefined`

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but it doesn't seem to match the question. OP asked about mocking a private function rather than the private method of a class. Or maybe the answer indicates the module should be recreated as a class?

Answer (score 8):

There is no way through the nature of JavaScript. The function is bound to the scope of the module, so there is no way to know that this function exists from the outside, so no way to access the function and in the end no way to mock it.

Maybe more important, you should not test on the internals of the object under test but only the public API. Cause that is everything that counts. No one cares how stuff is done internally as long as the public API stays stable.

Comment: When I was using "tape" and "ava" I was able to mock private functions by using "babel-plugin-rewire". About testing private functions I disagree since it violates the principles of TDD.

Comment: The nature of javascript is "do whatever you want, whenever you want." There's nothing stopping you from inserting a like-named function with which to assert code flow.

Comment: The nature of unit testing requires to spy and mock away stuff that is attached to the unit to be tested.

Comment: Does it have to violate TDD? What about writing a section of test cases that _indirectly_ test all paths in a private function, by calling its public parent?

Comment: Re "you should not test on the internals of the object under test". Even following this pattern, there are situations that come up where it's useful to mock internals.

Answer (score 6):

Another option would be an explicit cast:

```js
const spy = jest.spyOn((someInstance as unknown) as { privateMethod: SomeClass['privateMethod'] }, 'privateMethod');
```

It's a bit lengthy, but it has the advantage of keeping the typing of the private method for subsequent checks like `spy.hasBeenCalledWith(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling a function (`funA`) inside another function (`funB`) but you want your tests to use a mocked version of `funA`, refactor `funA` to use a class for its implementation, then mock a method on the class' prototype.

Suppose you have this:

```
async function goodsDetails({ code }) {
   return goodsNameFor(code);
}
async function goodsNameFor(code) { 
  // ... perform long running operation
  return 'xyz'
}
```

If you want to mock `goodsNameFor` so that when you're testing `goodsDetails` function you use the goodsNameFor, then change the implementation of `goodsNameFor` to be like this:

```
class GoodsNameCommand {
  constructor({ code }) {
    this.code = code;
  }
  async executeAsync() {
       // ... perform long running operation
       return 'xyz'
  }
}
async function goodsNameFor(code) { 
  // ... perform long running operation
  return new GoodsNameCommand().executeAsync();
}
```

Then at the top of your test class have this:

```
requiredJest.spyOn(GoodsNameCommand.prototype, 'executeAsync')
.mockResolvedValue('Webstorm');
```

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way I found to `spyOn` private methods using `ts-jest`.

First assume following example class with private method `doStuff` you wanna spy on:

```
class Example{
 private doStuff(): void {
  ...doing stuff
 }
}

const example = new Example();
```

Then is how you write a spy

```
jest.spyOn(example as any, 'doStuff');
```