# How do I mock a function being used by my React Component in Jest testing?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

So I have something like the following:

```
function calculate = (value) => { return value + somecalculations }

class MyComponent extends React.Component {

   ...

   render() {
       if (calcuate(this.props.value) === 1) {
          return(<MyComponentVersion1 />)
       } else {
          return <MyComponentVersion2 />
       }
   }
}
```

My question is, when doing jest unit testing, I want to be able to mock the function calculate().   But the function is global to that file, and is not part of my react component.  Is there a way to mock this function so it always returns say 1?  Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to mock private functions with Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265944/is-there-any-way-to-mock-private-functions-with-jest)

Comment: It's not exported or exposed in any other way? I mean, what's the purpose in testing internal functionality? The way the code is written now you'd need to change `value`. If you need to mock `calculate` then it sounds like it should be testable on its own, hence exported or in a separate module, then this question goes away. (Yes, things like rewire work, but it's almost always a substitute for appropriate design, IMO.)

Comment: You are controlling the value that gets passed to `calculate` so by passing certain values to your component you will be expecting it to behave in a predictable way. Test these scenarios don't bother testing calculate itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this without any extra dependencies (like a mocking library), you should be able to use dependency injection by telling `MyComponent` which function to use by setting it in a prop on your component to achieve this, like so:

```
calculate = (value) => { return value + somecalculations }

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.calculate = this.props.calculate || calculate
    }

    render() {
        if (this.calculate(this.props.value) === 1 {
            return (<MyComponentVersion1 />)
        } else {
            return (<MyComponentVersion2 />)
        }
    }
}
```

...and then, in your test, you can use a mock-calculate function:

```
test('put a really good test description here', () => {
    const mockCalculate = () => 1
    const myTestSubject = (<MyComponent calculate={mockCalculate} value={whatever}/>)
    // the rest of your test
})
```

If you want to use an actual mocking library instead, maybe try [sinon.js Mocks](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/mocks/).

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to access the `calculate` function from outside of the file. The easiest way to do this would be to export the function separately:

```
export function calculate () {
  // ...
}
```

This option is also minimally invasive to your source code.