# testing private methods in typescript with jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs

In the below code my test case was passed as expected but i am using stryker for mutation testing , handleError function is survived in mutation testing , so i want to kill the mutant by testing the handleError function is being called or not. need to help to test the private function.

i tried spyOn but didn't work

```
const orderBuilderSpy = jest.spyOn(orderBuilder, 'build')
const handleError = jest.fn()
expect(rderBuilderSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(handleError)
```

```js
// code written in nestJS/typescript

export class OrderBuilder {
  private amount: number

  public withAmount(amount: number): BuyOrderBuilder {
    this.amount = amount
    return this
  }


  public build(): TransactionRequest {
    this.handleError()
    return {
      amount: this.amount,
      acceptedWarningRules: [
        {
          ruleNumber: 4464
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  private handleError() {
    const errors: string[] = []
    const dynamicFields: string[] = [
      'amount',
    ]
    dynamicFields.forEach((field: string) => {
      if (!this[field]) {
        errors.push(field)
      }
    })
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      const errorMessage = errors.join()
      throw new Error(`missing ${errorMessage} field in order`)
    }
  }

}


// test
describe('Order Builder', () => {
  it('should test the handleError', () => {
    const orderBuilder = new OrderBuilder()
    const errorMessage = new Error(
      `missing amount field in order`
    )
    try {
      orderBuilder.build()
    } catch (error) {
      expect(error).toEqual(errorMessage)
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It looks like you are wanting to verify that `handleError` gets called when `build` runs.

Private methods are compiled to normal JavaScript prototype methods, so you can use the `any` type to let the spy creation pass through the TypeScript type checking.

Here is a highly simplified example:

```
class OrderBuilder {
  public build() {
    this.handleError()
  }
  private handleError() {
    throw new Error('missing ... field in order')
  }
}

describe('Order Builder', () => {
  it('should test the handleError', () => {
    const handleErrorSpy = jest.spyOn(OrderBuilder.prototype as any, 'handleError');
    const orderBuilder = new OrderBuilder()
    expect(() => orderBuilder.build()).toThrow('missing ... field in order');  // Success!
    expect(handleErrorSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
  });
});
```

Comment: This one is really nice example for mocking out private methods in a javascript class. I have been trying out different ways jest.fn(), jest.spyOn() but couldn't make it work earlier. But now I do.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if the `handleError` is an arrow function and thus a property of the object?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
const handleErrorSpy = jest.spyOn(OrderBuilder.prototype  as unknown as keyof typeof OrderBuilder, 'handleError');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// @ts-expect-error(TS2769)
cons spy = jest.spyOn(OrderBuilder, 'handleError');
```