# Cannot spy the getNotification() property because it is not a function; undefined given instead

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, karma-jasmine

I am getting this error in jest spyOn in angular test cases.
getNotification is a private method defined in the file. This is the test case written:

```
    const errorSpy = jest.spyOn(service as any, 'getNotification');
    const spy = jest
  .spyOn(service, 'func')
  .mockReturnValue(throwError('error'));
actions$ = of(abc);
effects.abc$.subscribe((res) => {
  expect(errorSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(res).toEqual(funcFail({ error: 'error' }));
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  done();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the function is private, you can't directly access it. So instead use the `prototype` to get access to the function:

```
const errorSpy = jest.spyOn(service.prototype as any, 'getNotification');
```

Here is a related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56045577/10781739