# how to write test case for a private function in Interceptor in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-http-interceptors

This is my interceptor code. How to write test cases for  private function handleError400.This function I'm using to logout when session expire. I don't know how write this.

```
  return next.handle(this.addTokenToRequest(request, this.auth.getAuthorizationToken()))
      .pipe(
        catchError(err => {
          if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            switch ((err as HttpErrorResponse).status) {
              case 400:
                return this.handle400Error(err);
              case 401:
                if (request.url.endsWith(constants.endpoints.auth)) {
                  return throwError(err);
                }
                const expiresTime = new Date(localStorage.getItem(constants.localStorage.tokenExpiresTime));
                if (expiresTime.getTime() > new Date().getTime()) {
                  this.logout();
                  return throwError(err);
                }
                return this.handle401Error(request, next);
              default:
                return throwError(err);
            }
          } else {
            return throwError(err);
          }
        }));
  }

  private logout(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['auth/login']);
  }

  private addTokenToRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string): HttpRequest<any> {
    if (request.headers.get('x-skip-auth-token')) {
      return request.clone({ headers: new HttpHeaders() });
    } else {
      if (request.body instanceof FormData) {
        return request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: token
          }
        });
      } else {
        return request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }

  private handle400Error(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (err && err.status === 400 && err.error && err.error.error_message === 'Access token or Refresh token is invalid') {
      return this.logout();
    }
    return throwError(err);
  }

  private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): any {
    const authResponse = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(constants.localStorage.authResponse) || '{}');
    if (authResponse) {
      const promise: Promise<AuthResponseModel> = this.auth.refreshToken(authResponse).toPromise<AuthResponseModel>();
      promise.then(res => {
        if (res) {
          localStorage.setItem(constants.localStorage.tokenExpiresTime, res.expires_in);
          localStorage.setItem(constants.localStorage.authResponse, JSON.stringify(res));
          return next.handle(this.addTokenToRequest(request, res.access_token));
        } else {
          return this.logout() as any;
        }
      });
      promise.catch(() => {
        return this.logout() as any;
      });
    }
  }
```

> I have tried to write test case like this but not able to spyon handleError400 function.Because it showing an error that *'Argument of type '"handleError400"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"intercept"''.*

```
 it('should  call handle400 function ', () => {
    const error = new HttpErrorResponse({
      status: 400,
      statusText: 'ok',
      url: 'url',

    });
    const interceptor: AuthInterceptor = TestBed.inject(AuthInterceptor);
    const handleerrorspy = spyOn(interceptor, 'handleError400').and.returnValue(
      of(error)
    );
    expect(handleerrorspy.calls.any()).toEqual(true);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

There're no straightforward answers to this. Although, there're some "hack" like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56045577/1589218), testing private function has long been a debatable topic.

In your case you can test the private function by having multiple test cases on the `intercept` method, one for each error code (e.g. 400, 401) and check if the output is as expected.