# Testing a private method in typescript using jest throws an error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test the `check` method which is a private method.

```
class Example {
  private check = async (x: string) => {
    //my code
  };
  public build() {
    const x: string = 'check';
    await this.check(x);
  }
}
```

Below is how i am testing the private method:

```
describe('Example', () => {
  it('should test the private method', () => {
    const handlePrivate = jest.spyOn(Example.prototype as any, 'check');

    expect(handlePrivate).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

But an error is being thrown stating that

> Cannot spy the check property because it is not a function; undefined given instead

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265944/is-there-any-way-to-mock-private-functions-with-jest

Comment: @RedBaron i have already gone through this link,it wasn't of much help.

Comment: `Example.prototype` won't have the `check` because it is defined as instance member

Comment: Also you don't show how you create an instance within the test and actually call the method..

Comment: @AlekseyL. i was following this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56044471/testing-private-functions-in-typescript-with-jest

Comment: @AlekseyL. could you suggest something other than the method suggested in the above link ?

Comment: First you should the real test (when you create `new Example` and call the `build`)